# Directive Parameters Nested Controller Simple Example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive

**Here is the code**

```
app.directive('hello', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Angular/Modules/Selector.html",
        controller: function () {
          this.message = [want the attribute message here]
        }
    };
});
```

**And the markup**

```
<hello message="hello world instance 1"></hello>

<hello message="hello world instance 2"></hello>
```

**Finally, The Question**

How can I get the attribute into the controller instance for each hello element?

**Binding dataSource attribute**

```
<hello ... datasource="/jsonData.json"></hello>

<hello ... datasource="/otherJsonData.json"></hello>
```

**More Controller Code**

```
$http.get($attrs.datasource).success(function (data) { ... });\
```

The datasource is shared but I need two separate instances.

Comment: [Open the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) and scroll until the `controller` part, or even the `scope` one if needed.

Comment: `controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) { console.log($attrs.message); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, to Blackhole for your advice!

**Working Code**

I can get the attributes now as he explained. I did notice that the attributes strangely change to all lower case but that is fine with me. Also the **Scope: { }** does the trick for creating isolated instances.

```
app.directive('selector', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Angular/Modules/Selector.html",
        scope : {},
        controller:  function ($http, $scope, $element, $attrs) {
           ...
            this.displayField = $attrs.displayfield;
           ...
            $http.get($attrs.datasource).success(function (data) {
            ...
            });
        },
        controllerAs : "selector"
    };
});
```

**The Markup**

Nothing much changed except the new attributes I added instead of message.

```
<selector id="selector1" datasource="/Company/CompanyListViewData2"
    displayfield="Name"></selector>
<selector id="selector2" datasource="/Employee/SimpleEmployeeListViewData"
    displayfield="LastNameFirstName"></selector>
```

Thanks again, this works great!